# How to create a list based on 2 conditions from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe :

```
 A       B      C
 1       1     100
 1       1     101
 1       5     102
 2       6     103
 2       6     104
 3      19     105
 3      20     106
...    ...      ...
 n
```

From each index of 'A' **AND** each index of the column 'B' I would like to obtain a list that respects the 2 conditions based on 'C' values for the whole dataframe.

For example, I would like this output:

```
l1 = [100, 101]
l2 = [103,104]
l3 = [105, 106]
etc.
```

Can you help please ? Thanks !

Comment: `From each index of 'A' AND each index of the column 'B'` - expected output is different

Comment: `list that respects the 2 conditions based on 'C' values` - what is conditions ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `pd.Series` slices to get just the first two elements in a list -

```py
df.groupby('A')['C'].apply(lambda x: list(x[:2]))
```

**Output**

```
A
1    [100, 101]
2    [103, 104]
3    [105, 106]
```

Comment: like alternative solution without `iloc` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If need first 2 rows per groups by `A` column use:

```
s = df.groupby('A').head(2).groupby('A')['C'].agg(list)

#alternative solution
#s = df.groupby('A')['C'].agg(lambda x: list(x.iloc[:2]))
print (s)
A
1    [100, 101]
2    [103, 104]
3    [105, 106]
Name: C, dtype: object


d = df.groupby('A').head(2).groupby('A')['C'].agg(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: [100, 101], 2: [103, 104], 3: [105, 106]}

print (d[1])
[100, 101]
```